# Check Box in ASP.NET page is not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using Grid View and inside grid view template defined for checkbox. I have used this criteria on various pages. But on some asp pages check box is not true as i have checked them it will always return property `Checked = false`.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox_ID" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean( Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "COLUMN_NAME"))) %>' /> 
</ItemTemplate>
```

Template is defined above.
I am using foreach loop to get rows then cell and then `FindControl()` method to find the checkbox.

Comment: Can you also add the codebehind code how you are accessing it?

Comment: Use [link](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to look the value sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is code behind how i access it.

```
 CheckBox chkRow = (row.Cells[GetColumnIndexByName(Grv_h, "Authorize")].FindControl("chkBox_ID") as CheckBox);
```